# Cannot access Mac hard drive

Tags: hardware, macbook

I have an old MAC hard drive I am trying to recover using an inateck housing.  when I plug it in via USB and try to access the desktop folder via the users file I receive the following statement:

> This folder does not belong to you.  You don't have permission to view
>   this folder

There is so much data on this drive that I have got to get to, any help will be seriously appreciated.

Comment: Try running `sudo -i pantheon-files` in  a terminal and then accessing your files

Comment: That worked to get me to a password prompt, but it would not let me enter the password.

Comment: bernie@bernie-SEPIOnotebook:~$ sudo -i pantheon-files
[sudo] password for bernie:

Comment: Try right clicking files on Plank and clicking **New Window As Administrator**

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what is Plank?

Comment: OH my, it might have worked

Comment: I added it as an answer. Mark it as accepted

Comment: Mark as answer to help future users

Answer (score 1):

Try right clicking files on Plank and clicking **New Window As Administrator**. Then enter your password and press enter

You should be able to access the MAC drive now